# Does iPad app have to support landscape and portrait?

Tags: ios, ipad

Do iPad apps have to support portrait and landscape in order to be accepted into the App Store?

EDIT:  My app is a business app selling things like Amazon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must support both types of one kind of orientation at the minimum. Portrait & PortraitUpsideDown AND/OR landscape left/right. Will pull up the link asap.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1689/_index.html

And what I mentioned depends on your app. For games mostly one kind of orientation is enough as it doesn't make sense sometimes to support the other orientation. Even then you must support both left/right OR normal/upside down ones. Depends on your app.

For non-gaming apps, I think it is recommended to support all 4.

Comment: Well Cut The Rope only supports one portrait orientation. The so called same rules don't apply to all the same way.

Comment: iPad. Cut the rope on iPad does only one portrait? Supporting upside down on iPhone makes ZERO sense though. The OP implied iPad for which upside down makes sense.

Comment: this document has been retired. it seems that you can refer to this one https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1588/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

App Specs doesn’t says anything specific to portrait and landscape mode, but yes its a recommended feature as mentioned in the iPad Application Human Behavior guideline.