# How to stop auto rotation?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, orientation

1st

[image]

2nd

[image]

3rd

```
 override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
```

i tried this tree even though its didn't stop rotation :(

is there any problem because i am using constraints for all device [image]

please help me what i have to do ,how to stop the orientation

**Only in ipad this problem came**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed just in iPad.
The app which runs on iPad must support both types of one kind of orientation at the minimum.
See more in [Does iPad app have to support landscape and portrait?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5776130/4975761)

however , you can add this code in every view controller of your project to work around.

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .Portrait;
}
```